# Connecting my Raspberry Pi 0 W

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero

I was wondering which type of HDMI I should use to connect my Raspberry pi to my monitor, it says HDMI on the side but I dont appear to have any cables of the type, I would like to buy the cable but I dont know which type it is.

Comment: Please read this on ["What I should do if someone answers my question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a HDMI cable with a **micro** HDMI male connector on one side. There are also cables available with *mini* connector but that will not fit. For example you can use one of these [hdmi micro to hdmi cables](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi+micro+to+hdmi+cable).

**UPDATE**
As corrected by some comments I was wrong with a **Pi Zero**. This model uses a **mini** HDMI connector as shown at https://www.amazon.co.uk/AmazonBasics-High-Speed-Mini-HDMI-HDMI-Cable-Black/dp/B014I8UEGY (Thanks to *@Dougie*).

Comment: The Pi Zero has mini

Comment: @Milliways Thanks for the hint, haven't known it because I have no Pi Zero. I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an HDMI to mini HDMI adapter or an HDMI to mini HDMI cable

Comment: That's not true. **mini* HDMI adapter will not fit.

Comment: For a RPi Zero you need something like https://www.amazon.co.uk/AmazonBasics-High-Speed-Mini-HDMI-HDMI-Cable-Black/dp/B014I8UEGY

Comment: It's a mini HDMI port:

https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero?view=all#video-out-2695512-17